# How to split columns when content isn't aligned

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a CSV file with survey data. One of the columns contains responses from a multi-select question. The values in that column are separated by ";"

```
|     Q10    |
----------------
| A; B; C    |
| A; B; D    |
| A; D       |
| A; D; E    |
| B; C; D; E |
```

I want to split the column into multiple columns, one for each option:

```
| A | B | C | D | E |
---------------------
| A | B | C |   |   |
| A | B |   | D |   |
| A |   |   | D |   |
| A |   |   | D | E |
|   | B | C | D | E |
```

Is there anyway to do this in excel or python or some other way?

Comment: Are you just searching for formatted output to the console for those values?

Comment: Split. Get dummies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple formula that does what is asked:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("; "&B$1&";","; "&$A2&";")),B$1,"")
```

This assumes there is always a space between the `;` and the look up value.  If not we can remove the space with substitute:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(";"&B$1&";",";"&SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","")&";")),B$1,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been answered but for those looking for a Python way to solve it, here it is (may be not the most efficient way though):

First split the column value, explode them and get the dummies. Next, group the dummy values together across the given 5 (or N) columns:

```
df['Q10'] = df['Q10'].str.split('; ')
df = df.explode('Q10')
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Q10'])
dummy_col_list = df.columns.tolist()
df['New'] = df.index
new_df = df.groupby('New')[dummy_col_list].sum().reset_index()
del new_df['New']
```

You will get:

```
   Q10_A  Q10_B  Q10_C  Q10_D  Q10_E
0      1      1      1      0      0
1      1      1      0      1      0
2      1      0      0      1      0
3      1      0      0      1      1
4      0      1      1      1      1
```

Now, if you want, you can rename the columns and replacing `1` with the column name:

```
colName = new_df.columns.tolist()
newColList = []
for i in colName:
    newColName = i.split('_', 1)[1]
    newColList.append(newColName)

new_df.columns = newColList

for col in list(new_df.columns):
    new_df[col] = np.where(new_df[col] == 1, col, '')
```

Final output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  A  B  C      
1  A  B     D   
2  A        D   
3  A        D  E
4     B  C  D  E
```

Comment: There are better answers on this kind of `one-hot encoding` relating questions. However, I guess because OP already accepted the answer, so other pandas/scipy experts don't bother to provide them.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do the job in python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['A'] = np.where(df.Q10.str.contains('A'), 'A', '')
df['B'] = np.where(df.Q10.str.contains('B'), 'B', '')
df['C'] = np.where(df.Q10.str.contains('C'), 'C', '')
df['D'] = np.where(df.Q10.str.contains('D'), 'D', '')
df['E'] = np.where(df.Q10.str.contains('E'), 'E', '')
df.drop('Q10', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
 0  A   B   C       
 1  A   B       D   
 2  A           D   
 3  A           D   E
 4      B   C   D   E
```

It's not the most efficient way, but it works ;)